# How to make DateTime::Duration output only in days?

Tags: perl

This code finds the difference between today and a fixed date.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

use DateTime ();
use DateTime::Duration ();
use DateTime::Format::Strptime ();

my $date = "23/05-2022";

my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern     => '%d/%m-%Y',
    time_zone   => 'local',
    );

$date = $parser->parse_datetime($date);

my $today = DateTime->today(time_zone=>'local');

my $d = DateTime::Duration->new($today - $date);

print Dumper $d->delta_days;
```

The problem is that is only outputs -22 days.

If I do `print Dumper $d;` I can see the -130 months as well.

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'seconds' => 0,
                 'minutes' => 0,
                 'end_of_month' => 'preserve',
                 'nanoseconds' => 0,
                 'days' => -22,
                 'months' => -130
               }, 'DateTime::Duration' );
```

How do I get it to output the result in days?

Doing

```
print Dumper $d->delta_days + $d->delta_months*30;
```

doesn't seam like an elegant solution.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

At first you need to do the correct subtraction. There exists `delta_md`, `delta_days`, `delta_ms` and `subtract_datetime_absolute`. Depending on which unit you later want, you need to pick the right subtraction. The problem is that not every unit is convertible later without time_zone information. Thats the reason why you need to pick the correct delta method.

For example a day can have 23 Hours or 24 or 25 Hours, depending on the time zone. Because of that, you need to specify how the subtraction should work. Because you want the days later, the subtraction need to focus on days, rather focus on hours. Don't use the overload feature, because it only does a best fit.

That means you need to do a `delta_days` subtraction.

```
my $dur = $date->delta_days($today);
```

Now $dur is a `DateTime::Duration` object. You need to knew that it always tries to best fit the days, weeks, years, months if possible. That means your days will split in weeks and days. Because this conversion is always a constant.

If you don't want this "best fit" you need to call the `in_units` method and convert it only to days.

```
my $days = $dur->in_units('days');
```

But like i said before `in_units` only can do a conversion where it is possible. A call with `in_units('hours')` will not work on this object and just return a zero because you cant convert days to hours. If you want hours for example, you need to do a `delta_ms`, and on this object you can call `in_units('hours')`

The complete example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $date = "23/05-2022";
my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern     => '%d/%m-%Y',
    time_zone   => 'local',
);
$date = $parser->parse_datetime($date);

my $today = DateTime->new(
    day   => 1,
    month => 7,
    year  => 2011,
    time_zone => 'local'
);  

my $dur = $date->delta_days($today);
say "Weeks:          ", $dur->weeks;
say "Days:           ", $dur->days;
say "Absolute Days:  ", $dur->in_units('days');
say "Absolute Hours: ", $date->delta_ms($today)->in_units('hours');
```

The output of this program is:

```
Weeks:          568
Days:           3
Absolute Days:  3979
Absolute Hours: 95496
```

And just for info:
1) You don't need to load `DateTime::Duration` its get loaded with `DateTime`.
2) You dont need (). These modules are OOP and don't export/import anything.

Comment: I often use `()` in `use` statements anyway.  Just because a module is OO doesn't mean it has no exports.  When you use `()`, you _know_ it's not exporting anything into your script (without even looking at the module).

Comment: Absolutely amazing. Thanks =)

Comment: @Sid Burn : I just noticed that it always gives a positive number of days when using `$dur->in_units('days')`. Is it possible to get signed number of days?

Comment: It calculates the delta between two dates. That's always positive. If you want a negative number, you need to check which date is greater and multiple the result with -1.

Answer (score 2):

From a quick read of the [DateTime module doc](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-0.70/lib/DateTime.pm), I don't believe that

```
DateTime::Duration->new($today - $date)
```

will do what you expect.  I believe you need to use

```
$dur = $today->subtract_datetime($date)
```

The type of `$dur` is not immediately clear from the docs, however.

Comment: It outputs the same, but I suppose `subtract_datetime()` is made for the purpose, so I'll use that.

Comment: Actually, because of DateTime's overloading cleverness, you can even just do: my $dur = $today - $date;