# DateTime::subtract_datetime returns zero for difference in hours

Tags: perl, datetime

Here is a minimal working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime;

my $now = DateTime->new(day => 17,
                         month=> 10,
                         year => 2014,);

my $date = DateTime->new(day => 3,
                         month=> 10,
                         year => 2014,
                     );

my $dur = $now->subtract_datetime($date);
print 'hours = ', $dur->hours(), "\n";
```

When I run it on my server I get this:

```
hours = 0
```

It's incorrect. The correct answer is 14 days = 336 hours.

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all days have 24 hours, so 14 days is not always 336 hours. If you want the difference in hours, you'll have to specifically ask for that (or in something that can be converted to hours such as minutes). `delta_ms` is the method to do that.

```
 my $now = DateTime->new(day => 17,
                         month=> 10,
                         year => 2014,);

 my $date = DateTime->new(day => 3,
                         month=> 10,
                         year => 2014,
                     );

 my $dur = $now->delta_ms($date);
 print 'hours = ', $dur->in_units('hours'), "\n";
```

Which returns what you want.

See [How to make DateTime::Duration output only in days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549522/how-to-make-datetimeduration-output-only-in-days) for more discussion.