# DateTime.pm code to determine days between dates

Tags: perl, datetime

I have a function I'm trying to re-create using the DateTime module in Perl:

```
$x=dates_difference($year,$month,$day,$cyear,$curmon,$cmday)
```

given two dates, the current date/time in the format of: $cyear, $cmon, $cmday (year, month number, day of month number) and another date that will be earlier in the same format: $year, $month, $day, I want to return the number of days between the two dates.  I don't need it to be 100% precise, as long as it's +/- a day or two so time and timezones don't really matter.

I've been reading through various examples and can't find anything very clear.

I tried this:

```
$x = $dtcurrent->subtract_datetime_absolute($dt1);
```

and got an error `DateTime::Duration does not overload comparison. See the documentation on the compare() method for details.`

Example:

```
$x = $dtcurrent->delta_days($dt1);
if ($x > 30) ...
```

it does not appear to be returning a number I can use in a numeric comparison.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What examples are you looking at and in what way do you judge them unclear?

Comment: One sec.. let me get this format

Comment: I tried this: $x=$dtcurrent->subtract_datetime_absolute($dt1);

and got an error

DateTime::Duration does not overload comparison.  See the documentation on the compare() method for details.

Comment: Most of the examples I've found online use an outdated Date::Calc module.

Comment: Please add this to your question, and show input for which you get errors.

Comment: Example:  
    $x=$dtcurrent->delta_days($dt1);
    if ($x>30) ...

it does not appear to be returning a number I can use in a numeric comparison

Comment: Please see documentation -- [delta_days](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.26/lib/DateTime.pm#$dt-%3Edelta_days%28_$datetime_%29) returns an object.

Comment: forgive me but I'm not very familiar with OOP.. this is a very old script that was not using any OOP... I just need an integer returned so I can make this old script continue to function properly because the old library upon which it relied is no longer available.

Comment: What is the proper code to return an integer that represents the difference between two dates using DateTime routines?    I do not know how to handle a DateTime:duration object.   This is why I'm asking.

Comment: This now makes far more sense.  Please update the question with all this information -- what you tried and what doesn't work (and how) or you don't know how to do.  That's precisely what should be in the question.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6550372/5830574).

Comment: Thanks for the improvement Sebastian :)

Comment: The questions ask for the difference between two dates, but a number of solution show the difference between today and another date. Which one do you want?

Comment: No need to reach for DateTime here. Time::Piece has been a standard part of the Perl distribution since 5.10 and will handle this fine.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `delta_days`.

```
sub dates_difference {
   my ($year1, $month1, $day2, $year2, $mon2, $day2) = @_;
   my $dt1 = DateTime->new( year => $year1, month => $month1, day => $day1, time_zone => 'floating' );
   my $dt2 = DateTime->new( year => $year2, month => $month2, day => $day2, time_zone => 'floating' );
   return $dt2->delta_days($dt1)->in_units('days');
}
```

The following is more efficient:

```
sub dates_difference {
   my ($year1, $month1, $day2, $year2, $mon2, $day2) = @_;
   my $dt1 = DateTime->new( year => $year1, month => $month1, day => $day1, time_zone => 'floating' );
   my $dt2 = DateTime->new( year => $year2, month => $month2, day => $day2, time_zone => 'floating' );
   return abs( ( $dt2->local_rd_values )[0] - ( $dt1->local_rd_values )[0] );
}
```

If you want the difference to be signed, use the following:

```
sub dates_difference {
   my ($year1, $month1, $day2, $year2, $mon2, $day2) = @_;
   my $dt1 = DateTime->new( year => $year1, month => $month1, day => $day1, time_zone => 'floating' );
   my $dt2 = DateTime->new( year => $year2, month => $month2, day => $day2, time_zone => 'floating' );
   return ( $dt2->local_rd_values )[0] - ( $dt1->local_rd_values )[0];
}
```

Comment: `->delta_days->days` doesn't return anything useful, see my sample.

Comment: @Sebastian, I thought I needed `in_units`, but then I thought otherwise. Oops. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the core [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) module. It's much lighter-weight than `DateTime` and does all that is necessary

Here's some example code for you

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece ();

my $x = dates_difference(2017, 1, 1, 2016, 5, 9);

say "$x days until the New Year";


sub dates_difference {
    my ($y, $m, $d, $cy, $cm, $cd) = @_;
    my $date  = Time::Piece->strptime("$y $m $d", '%Y %m %d');
    my $cdate = Time::Piece->strptime("$cy $cm $cd", '%Y %m %d');
    ($date - $cdate)->days;
}
```

#### output

```
237 days until the New Year
```

Answer (score 0):

Assembling your code lines to an example:

```
my $dtcurrent = DateTime->new(
    year  => 2016,
    month => 5,
    day   => 9,
);
my $old = DateTime->new(
    year  => 2016,
    month => 1,
    day   => 1,
);
```

(I'm using a fixed `$dtcurrent` for easier explanation of the calculation results. Should be `$dtcurrent = DateTime->now` in production.)

```
my $distance = $old->delta_days($dtcurrent);
```

`$distance` is a `DateTime::Duration` object which has different properties:

```
print $distance->years;
0
```

No surprise: 2016 -> 2016 is 0 years difference.

```
print $distance->months;
0

print $distance->days;
3
```

What happend? The `DateTime` manual says:

> The "delta_days()" method returns a duration which contains only days.

Not what you expected. But try `->in_units`:

```
print $distance->in_units('days');
129
```

**Alternate: Date::Calc**

I'd prefer `Date::Calc` for this usage case:

```
use Date::Calc qw(Delta_Days Today);
print Delta_Days(Today(), 2016, 1, 1);
-129
```

Swap `Today()` and the date to get a positive number. `Today()` may also be replaced by another `$year, $month, $day`.

**Alternate: Timestamps**

```
use Time::Local qw( timegm ); # Core module

my ($year_now, $month_now, $day_now) = ( localtime(time) )[5,4,3];

my $ts     = timegm($year,     $month,     $day,     0, 0, 0);
my $ts_now = timegm($year_now, $month_now, $day_now, 0, 0, 0);

my $days = int(abs(($ts_now - $ts)) / (24*60*60));
```

`timegm` does the opposite of `gmtime`: Convert date parts into a timestamp. Since all gmtime days have 24*60*60 seconds, we can find the number of days between two dates by finding the timestamps of those dates in gmt, calculating the difference, and dividing by 24*60*60. This is obviously very complicated and error prone.

Comment: Is Date::Calc part of Perl core whereas DateCalc.pm has to be installed via cpan?

Comment: @Arkan No and no. Date::Calc isn't in core (although it is on CPAN); Date::DateCalc isn't on CPAN.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/index-modules-D.html states that neither `DateTime` nor `Date::Calc` are core modules. I just added a third option without any non-core modules, but it's not very accurate. I'd prefer getting `Date::Calc`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with that appears to work..

```
use DateTime;

my $dt_now = DateTime->now( time_zone => 'local' )->set_time_zone('floating');

my $dt1 = DateTime->new(
   year      => $year,
   month     => $month,
   day       => $day,
   time_zone => 'floating',
);

my $days = $dt_now->delta_days($dt1)->in_units('days');
```

Comment: The question asked about two arbitrary dates, not local-today and another.